# Converting SQL Timestamp With Magento To Use PHP Formatting

Tags: php, sql, magento

lets say that my entity table contains a created_at column.
In calling the entity's time that it was created i would do something like:

```
$entity = Mage::getModel('namespace/entity')->load(1);
//and if I want the time it was created at I would do
$created = $entity->getCreatedAt();
```

The problem is, this returns an ugly timestamp that is not very useful to the frontend user in many cases.
Example timestamp: 2013-10-25 14:00:28

What is the best way to provide formatting to the timestamp to make it user readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made it possible to format the date:

```
$output_date = date('d-m-Y', Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp($entity->getCreatedAt()));
```